# XMLHttpRequest :: audio fails loading

Tags: javascript, audio, xmlhttprequest

I am using `python`'s `SimpleHTTPServer`to serve a test page on `localhost`.

I have an empty `src` for the `audio` tag.

```
<audio id="audio" src=" "></audio>
```

And this the request:

```
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/audio/song.wav", true);
request.responseType = "blob";    
request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var src = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    audio.src = src;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
request.send();
</script>
```

But `XHR`failed loading. Where is the bug?

Comment: Are any error messages logged at `console` ? Are you requesting file before `audio` element is loaded into `document` ?

Comment: @guest271314 console.log = `XHR failed loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/audio/song.wav, anonymous function (request.send( )`. <audio> is prior to <script> on document

Comment: Why does file fail to load ? Are you referencing the correct path ? Are any errors logged at `terminal` by `SimpleHTTPServer` ? If you navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/audio/song.wav` is the file present ?

Comment: It is playing now. I had, apart from the `<audio id="audio" src=" "></audio>`, other audio files being preloaded as well., when I removed them, audio loaded and played. btw, do you know why other preloaded audio files prevents `XMLHttpRequest` from loading?

Comment: _"btw, do you know why other preloaded audio files prevents `XMLHttpRequest` from loading?"_ Not certain; can you include "preloaded audio files" portion of `html` , `js` at Question ? Do elements in `document` have duplicate `id`s ?

Comment: @guest271314 no duplicates. I use to have, bellow `<audio id="audio" src=" "></audio>` other preloaded audios:
`<audio id=song1" src="audio/song1.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="song2" src="audio/song2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>` when I removed them, the dynamically included audio loaded, but not before.

Comment: Tried removing `preload` attribute ? See `auto` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload